# Docker Auto scaling

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

is there any way to Auto scale the docker container in a Swarm mode.  Base on CPU, network or memory usage it reaches a level Ex 70 %  it has to automatically start a new container in the cluster.  once the load goes down it automatically scale down the container. ( in windows container )

Is there any way to configure. and monitor the swarm cluster

Answer (score 1):

Swarm does not include batteries for containers horizontal autoscaling either using metrics like CPU or not, and although it's possible to do that using Docker's API you'd need some scripting and monitoring tools to be able to do that.

There are many open issues in GitHub's Docker projects for those features to be added to Swarm ([here](https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/2151) and [here](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/2354)) and similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736620/autoscale-docker-swarm-services) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668621/how-to-configure-autoscaling-on-docker-swarm) in SO.

The [Orbiter project](https://gianarb.it/blog/orbiter-the-swarm-autoscaler-moves) looks promising to overcome current Swarm's lack of features, but you'll need a monitoring tool that would trigger the scale up and scale down actions. If you really need those features you may have to evaluate Kubernetes in the meantime.